# Driving an electromagnet through a shift register?

Tags: shift-register, high-current

I want to know if it is reasonable to use a shift register to control electromagnets. We want to drive electromagnets with about 400-500mA.  The TPIC6B595 [data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpic6b595.pdf) claims "Each output provides a 500-mA typical current limit at TC = 25°C."  Is it reasonable to run 2 or 3 outputs at 500mA at once?  Is it poor to chain one electromagnet to two outputs such that we can achieve more than 500mA through one magnet?

Also, is there a way to search for shift registers based on continuous current capability?  Digikey does not have this option, and I am not sure how one would go about this without scanning through every individual data sheet.

Comment: Read datasheet carefully. If you want to use all outputs, the continuous current it is 150mA/output. If you use just ONE out then the maximum current is 500mA with some restrictions about the pulse falling time caused by the inductance of electromagnet. In general it is possible to use two DMOS transistors in parallel (with or without ballast resistors) but I'm not sure if this transistors are exactly the same. It is better to use an external  transistor, like TIP41C or ULN2803 array, to drive your electromagnets

Comment: "Tc = 25°C" this is an impossible spec for you to meet in real life. It means you have to hold the case at room temperature (no warmer) even though it's dissipating a lot of heat- so an infinitely big heat sink. You have to derate the limit significantly to stay within specifications over a sensible temperature range.

Answer (score 3):

The *absolute maximum* current ratings are 500 mA, and generally one should not design a circuit to place components at absolute max conditions for very long (if at all; you might have one part on the extreme end of it's tolerance and all of a sudden you're exceeding maximums).

Reading deeper into the datasheet, it says the *absolute maximum **continuous** drain current (all outputs on)* is 150 mA, *pulsed* is 500 mA.  Peak drain current for a single output would be 500 mA.

It would be a better idea to use an external transistor and flyback diode to drive a moderate current device like your 0.5 A electromagnet.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you need actually **read the datasheet**, which makes it clear you can't run your magnets directly from this device as you intend.

However, this can be done with transistors between the shift register and the magnets.  This sort of thing is done all the time.  Microcontrollers routinely control large motors and the like from digital outputs that can source and sink only a few mA.  When the digital logicl doesn't have to provide the final current directly, you have access to many more options.